# how to open pdf file to another tab in browser using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

```
im making currently making my thesis about a record management of our university secretary.. in which all papers inside the office will be scanned and uploaded in the system.. i am using codeigniter..one of the feature in my system is to view the pdf file in other window of the browser. but my problem is, when i click the title. only blank page will be displayed in the other tab.. can you help me solve this one?? here is my code

controller:

 function viewMinutesFile(){
        if(isset($_GET['id'])){
            $id = $_GET['id'];
            $file = $this->minutes_model->getFile($id);

            $fp= fopen($file->path, "r");

            header("Cache-Control: maxage=1");
            header("Pragma: public");
            header("Content-type: application/pdf");
            header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=".$file->filename."");
            header("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data");
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
            header('Content-Length:' .filesize($file->path));
            ob_clean();
            flush();
            while (!feof($fp)){
                $buff = fread($fp,1024);
                print $buff;
            }
            exit;

        }
    }
```

code to open the file: this is my syntax to be clicked by the user so that pdf file will be open in the new tab
                File
                
                index.php/admin/viewMinutesFile? 
          id=" target="_tab">

Comment: Did you try `rel="external"` or `target="_blank"` instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this one with a static url. no need any extra words for that.

```
<a href="<?=base_url('any_folder_name/any_file.pdf')?>" target="_blank">Show My Pdf</a>
```

**New Update**

if its work for you then fetch pdf name from database and put the name in the view like

```
<a href="<?=base_url('index.php/admin/viewMinutesFile/'.$info['doc_id'])?>" target="_blank">Show My Pdf</a>
```

now in the controller

```
$this->load->helper('download');
if($this->uri->segment(3))
{
    $data   = file_get_contents('./file_path/'.$this->uri->segment(3));
}
$name   = $this->uri->segment(3);
force_download($name, $data);
```

Comment: it works for me..but i dont know how to make it dynamic, can you help me how to make it dynamic? :) this is my current code, <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/viewMinutesFile?id=<?php echo $info['doc_id']; ?>" target="_blank"> <?php echo $fileName; ?></a>

Comment: what is <?php echo $info['doc_id']; ?>? Is it the document id that you want see in different tab? Please see my updated answer

Comment: this will be the error,, A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: file_get_contents(./file_path/130): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: controllers/admin.php

Line Number: 750

Comment: 130 may be the id of a pdf file.provide the pdf file name instead of id.

Comment: how to change it to pdf file insted of id??

Comment: here is the error, A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: file_get_contents(./file_path/130): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: controllers/admin.php

Line Number: 750   this is my code in view: <a href="<?=base_url('index.php/admin/viewMinutesFile/'.$fileName)?>" target="_blank">Show My Pdf</a> and in controller,  function viewMinutesFile(){$this->load->helper('download');
if($this->uri->segment(3))
{
    $data = file_get_contents('./file_path/'.$this->uri->segment(3));
}
$name   = $this->uri->segment(3);
force_download($name, $data);}

Comment: first tell me what is 130?

Comment: 130 is the primarykey of the pdf file

Comment: is there any .pdf file belongs to 130,then put that .pdf file name instead of 130.now your $fileName=130.that's why the code is not working.

Comment: whats the code?can you show me? the error is in the controller, the file_get_contents

Comment: i change already into filename, so the error now is in my controller, ive just copy your code. but the error is  Message: file_get_contents(./file_path/Li_Yicheng.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: use your folder name instead of file_path in controller.i had given an example previously.

Comment: thank you sir. but i want in to view the file not download..the problem is, it automatically download the file.

Comment: it is already functioning but my problem is that, i want it to be view only.not to download..how to do it?

Comment: what is your <a></a> tag now ? please paste it.i want to see the link actually.

Comment: <a href="<?=base_url('index.php/admin/viewMinutesFile/'.$fileName)?>" target="_blank">Show My Pdf</a>

Comment: <a href="<?=base_url('the_folder_name_of_your_file/'.$fileName)?>" target="_blank">Show My Pdf</a>

Comment: sir you have fb?can i add u so that if i have any problem i can easily contact you?

Comment: that we can do but is your problem solved?Also its not allowed to access fb from office.

Comment: thank you sir for your effort. i can now view the pdf file :), thank you very much

Comment: thank you very much sir..my problem already solve..you have gmail?so that i can chat you anytime?

Answer (score 5):

well, you could add a link to file with `target="_blank"`, like

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(). 'your_controller/viewMinutesFile'; ?>" target="_blank">
    View Pdf
</a>
```

and in controller function:

```
function viewMinutesFile(){
    ....
    $file = $this->minutes_model->getFile($id);
    $this->output
           ->set_content_type('application/pdf')
           ->set_output(file_get_contents($your_pdf_file));
}
```

Comment: @kit i meant you could add a anchor link in your view file as mentioned aove to open the pdf in new file, you can use your controller function or the one i added as answer..

Comment: ill just copy what you have write above?

Answer (score 3):

Just create a link to a blank page and use this code in your controller:

```
public function myPdfPage(){
    $url = base_url('assets/your.pdf');
    $html = '<iframe src="'.$url.'" style="border:none; width: 100%; height: 100%"></iframe>';
    echo $html;
}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

you can try this on your **view** :

```
<a href="controller/viewfile/filename.anything">Filename</a>
```

and on your **controller**, you can try this, because this is works for me :

```
    function viewfile(){
        $fname = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $tofile= realpath("uploaddir/".$fname);
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
        readfile($tofile);
    }
```

hope this might help you...

Answer (score 1):

There is no any problem with your code you can open easily on next tab, like other pages only difference you have to change header description and it is make sure on your browser pdf reader add-ons are available, otherwise it will give you option to download.

Comment: what you want to change ?

Comment: actually,when i click the title.. it will be open in the next tab but contents of the pdf is not displayed.

Comment: you can check the correct path of pdf and you can check with another browser

Comment: i've already done itbut it is just the same..can i send to you my code and the sql so that you can try my system and suggest more? :)

Comment: nope..im uploading pdf file and i would like to view my uploaded file in the browser when i click the title of the file

Comment: do you have backgroung using the codeigniter??because i am using the code igniter framework

Comment: First, check upload is working perfectly then first open that pdf from folder using adobe reader, then if it is working then first open into browser with http path.

Comment: sorry for inconvenience because im just a newbie in ci :(

Answer (score 1):

You may just follow this.

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('your_controller/your_function','target="_blank"') ;?>
    //other input fields
<?php form_close();?>
```